# Ant properties override

Tags: java, ant, jenkins

I have a question, I have an build.properties where I have a property test=true;
and the ant target should be called only in case is test is true. I want to have that value as a default one. Is it possible somehow to change the value in Jenkins? I tried to set test=false, but seems that there was no effect. Some suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried simply putting `test=true` in the properties section of the "invoke Ant" build step in your Jenkins job?  Properties set there are treated the same way as properties passed to Ant via the command line, and thus should override anything set in your build script or properties files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this scenario you have to modify Ant script similarly like below, then it will work as you expected.
If not try similar kind of logic to set default and dynamic values for ant. Then if you pass value from Jenkins if it is -Dtest=true otherwise by default it will assign value to false

```
<condition property="test" value="${test}" else="false">
    <isset property="${test}" />
</condition>
```

Answer (score 1):

**To have an Ant target execute only on certain condition**

In your Ant build script, you want a target that only executes when a certain condition is met. It is easy to do using `if="property"` attribute of `<target>` tag, however that checks if property is *set*, not its value. And you are already setting the property to default `test=true`. So for your case, a little different method can be used.

```xml
<condition property="test.execute" value="${test}">
    <matches pattern="true" string="${test}"/>
</condition>

<target name="runtest" if="test.execute">
    <echo message="running tests"/>
</target>
```

This script checks the value of `${test}`, and if that matches to *text* `"true"`, it will set a value of `${test.execute}` to value of `${test}`. If not (i.e. anything other than "true"), then the property `${test.execute}` remains **unset**.

Finally, the target `runtest` will only execute if property `${test.execute}` is set.

Note: this will only work when that property remains unset. Even having `<property name="test.execute" value=""/>` in the build file or properties will break this.

**To pass a variable through Jenkins to Ant:**

- Select **Invoke Ant** build step
- Click **Advanced...**
- Under **Targets**, enter your usual targets (or leave empty for default)
- Under **Build File**, specify the build file (or leave empty for default `build.xml` in root of `$WORKSPACE`)
- Under **Properties**, enter your parameters in the format `param=value`. This is the same as using `-Dparam=value` on command line. Note that you do **not** need `-D` when specifying properties in this field in Jenkins.
- So, enter `test=false`

Comment: Thanks a lot, it almost worked. It is a shame that I cannot pick 2 answers as correct! But it helped a lot.

Comment: <matches pattern="true" string="${test}"/> somehow it just failed

Comment: Weird, this is a copy-n-paste from my xml that worked and there are no syntax errors. Oh well, glad you got it working anyways.

Answer (score 1):

With Ant 1.9.2 and up (It suppose to work with Ant 1.9.1, but I have problems with it), you can now use the [if:true](http://ant.apache.org/manual/index.html) parameter in most tasks:

```
<project default="test" xmlns:if="ant:if"> <!-- Note xmlns in the entity "project" -->
    <property name="run.this" value="true"/>
    <target name="test">
        <echo if:true="${run.this}">Run test target</echo>
    </target>
</project>
```

If I run:

```
$ ant
Buildfile: /Users/david/build.xml

test:
      [echo] Run test target

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 0 seconds
```

If I run:

```
ant -Drun.this=false  # Sets property run.this to "false"
test:

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 0 seconds
```

Note that the `if:true="${run.this}` prevents echo from executing when `run.this` is false.